# codeigniter's oauth sparks issue with linkedin Scope.

Tags: codeigniter, oauth, kohana, linkedin-api

I'm using [Oauth](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth) from sparks which is derived from kohana's [Oauth](https://github.com/kohana/oauth) implementation.
  I'm suceesfully able to fetch basic information from linkeidn but after adding  "r_emailaddress" scope I do not get email-address only basic info is being fetch.
  I'm adding scope follwong way in my controller

```
$consumer = $this->oauth->consumer(array(
            'key' => $config[$provider]['key'],
            'secret' => $config[$provider]['secret'],
            'scope'=> "r_emailaddress,r_fullprofile"
          ));
```

Any Clue would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved, I had to create another app or update existing.

Comment: The reason for this is that in early August LinkedIn added the email address to be accessible for newly created applications.  https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/17163#comment-17163